# database query questions or other solutions for comparing data between 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating Windows Application Form using Visual Studio 2010.
For now, I am in this situation:

I allow users to add items into the system, each item they may have different brand, cost & suppliers and selling price for different customers.

For example,
Item1, Name: ABC, Brand: TIM and
Item2, Name: ABC, Brand: LD.

when the users want to insert the cost and suppliers information into Item1, when they click on the "ShowCost" button, another Windows Form will pop out for the users to fill in. And I'm planning to use DataGridView for that. I'm planning to use the Item Name and Brand for identifying the cost and selling price for the item

So here's my question,
How do I set the query or other solutions in order to check that when the name and brand of the item that the users enter, will show up the cost and the price of the specific items? what is the query that i need to write?

I have created 3 database tables which are ItemInfo(Name, Brand, etc), CostList(Name, Brand, SuppliersName, Cost) and SellingPrice(Name, Brand, CustomersName, SellingPrice).
How do I compare the data from ItemInfo tables to show the data in CostList?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have google search for the information but none of them get to solve my questions.

Comment: It's quite hard to figure out exactly what your trying to achieve. What is you backend Database? is it MS Access or SQL? You may need to have a Junction Table for this project, as an Item can have multiple suppliers but each Supplier will only have one unique Item. Getting the database setup correctly is your first step. If i'm right in what i'm thinking, You could have 1 Item with 20 different suppliers?

Comment: sql, what I need to know is, when i click the "Show Cost" button, how do I check that the costs list is for the specific Item, not the other item. I am using ItemInfo Name and Brand to identify an item.

Comment: that's right, one item may have 20 different suppliers and of course, costs as different suppliers may have different price. I think for a long time and I can't figure out how, as I'm still new to this.

Comment: From your question and comments I believe that you still do not clearly have defined your database structure, tables, fields, primary keys, etc. Take a look to the [AdventureWorks database provided by Miscrosoft](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/). There are several versions of it, for each version of MSSQL Server. You will get a glimpse on how to setup a basic eCommerce database, with Products, Orders, Sales, etc.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help, I will study the knowledge that you all given, thanks!

Comment: As for queries, you will use LINQ, thats something else to study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a database you should consider using Primairy keys. That way you can store information about a certain item in another table. In all three tables you use Name and Brand. I would have modeled my tables like this:

**Items**

- ItemID (make this field an Auto incrementing integer field)
- ItemName
- Brand
- SupplierID
- Price

**Clients**

- ClientID
- ClientName
- DiscountPercentage
- PhoneNr

**Suppliers**

- SupplierID
- SupplierName

In the clients table the field SupplierID is a unique number. So when you want to refer to a supplier you simple fill in the SupplierID. For example in the items table the ItemID is the unique identifier for an item. The Supplier ID field is refers to the SupplierID field in the Suppliers table. In order to make sure your datamodel remains consistent I would recommend you to use Foreign key constraints. This makes sure you can not fill in any invalid ID's

Here's a short movie explaining some [SQL basics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpp28U_K9Lk)

Comment: thanks for the information, I will restructure my database again and may I search for your help again if I have any problems with it?

Comment: So, if i have 2 tables now, ItemInfo with ItemID as primary key, then another table, CostLists to show the item costs and supplier names which depends on the ItemInfo ItemID, should I put ItemID in CostList also? and how do I link them together?

Comment: Yes the Costlist should contain an item id. Otherwise you cannot say that Item A costs x. You can link tables together with Joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: ok last question, SELECT costprice.costid, costprice.suppliername, costprice.costprice FROM costprice INNER JOIN partsinfo ON costprice.partsid = partsinfo.partsid WHERE CostPrice.PartsID = (textbox1.text from another form) How can I pass the textbox1.text which is from another form to the query???

Comment: You where almost there ;)

`string qry = ¨SELECT costprice.costid, costprice.suppliername, costprice.costprice FROM costprice INNER JOIN partsinfo ON costprice.partsid = partsinfo.partsid WHERE partsinfo.partname = '" + textbox1.text + "'";`

So for instance if the value of your textbox = "screwdriver" then your query would look like:
`SELECT costprice.costid, costprice.suppliername, costprice.costprice FROM costprice INNER JOIN partsinfo ON costprice.partsid = partsinfo.partsid WHERE partsinfo.partname = 'Screwdriver'`

Comment: ok, thanks @sjuul janssen, u've been a great help to me, it needs some coding to pass the value of textbox1.text from another form to this form. i'll figure it out!

Comment: Jansseen, do u have any email or something? It seems like the system cannot get the value of my textbox, I would like to send to ur email and see if you can find out something? is that ok? If you're busy then it's ok